# SQL self-join to label nodes on binary search tree

Tags: sql, join

Would like feedback on my SQL (1) efficiency and (2) readability, and if the conditions I featured in my `CASE` statement could be transferred to a join, etc.

Here's the problem I'm solving:

> Say you have a table `bst` with a column of nodes and column or
>   corresponding parent nodes:
>
> ```
> node   Parent
> 1       2
> 2       5
> 3       5
> 4       3
> 5       NULL
> ```
>
> We want to write SQL such that we label each node as a “leaf”, “inner”
>   or “Root” node, such that for the nodes above we get:
>
> ```
> Node    Label
> 1       Leaf
> 2       Inner
> 3       Inner
> 4       Leaf
> 5       Root
> ```

Here's my solution:

```
WITH join_table AS 
(
SELECT 
    a.node a_node,
    a.parent a_parent,
    b.node b_node, 
    b.parent b_parent
 FROM
    bst a 
 LEFT JOIN 
    bst b ON a.parent = b.node 
 )

 SELECT 
    a_node as Node, 
    CASE 
        WHEN b_node IS NOT NULL and b_parent IS NOT NULL THEN 'Leaf'
        WHEN b_node IS NOT NULL and b_parent IS NULL THEN 'Inner'
        WHEN b_node IS NULL and b_parent IS NULL THEN 'Root'
        ELSE 'Error' 
    END AS Label 
 FROM 
    join_table
```

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you targeting?  (Apart from that, this is a really well-asked SQL question, so well done!)

Comment: @TobySpeight Let's just say Hive, but Postgres or MySQL would work too -- more focused on the underlying logic

Comment: It is possible to rewrite your query without `CASE`, however, it will not help the performance since you are reading the whole tables anyway. The sequential scan is inevitable in this case.

Comment: @RadimBača Feel free to post such a response

Comment: @zthomas.nc it would be a solution using `UNION ALL` which would lead to three sequential scans instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will work only on the dataset that you've mentioned. If you apply this code to another dataset it will throw up erroneous results.
Here is why:

1. Condition `b_node IS NULL and b_Parent is NULL` will always give correct result i.e. 'Root'
2. The conditions for 'Leaf' and 'Inner' will change depending on the dataset.
   let's assume 5 is not the parent root, instead it is an inner node and there is a parent node 6 above it and 6 also has a child node 7

So the table becomes

```
 1. a_node  a_parent b_node b_parent




 1. 1        2       2       5
 2. 2        5       5       6
 3. 3        5       5       6
 4. 4        3       3       5
 5. 5        6       6       NULL
 6. 6        NULL    NULL    NULL
 7. 7        6       6       NULL
```

here 2 and 3 are not nulls and will be marked as 'leaf' erroneously.

A better solution is this case is to use `CASE` to identify those nodes in `a_node` which can never be a parent in `a_parent` since they are leaf nodes.